# Determinant of complex block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices, schur-complement

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ invertible matrix. Let $a \in \Bbb C$, let $\alpha$ be a row $n$-tuple of complex numbers and let
$\beta$ be a column $n$-tuple of complex numbers. Show that

$$(\det(A))^{-1}\, \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}a & \alpha\\
\beta & A
\end{bmatrix}\right)=\det\left(a-\alpha A^{-1}\beta\right).$$

Can anyone show me how to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
(\det A)^{-1}
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
a & \alpha\\
\beta & A
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\det\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \left(\vec 0\right)^T\\
\vec 0 & A^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\right)\det\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
a & \alpha\\
\beta & A
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
\\ &=
\det\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \left(\vec 0\right)^T\\
\vec 0 & A^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & \alpha\\
\beta & A
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
\\
&= \det
\begin{bmatrix}
a & \alpha \\
A^{-1}\beta & I
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Where $\vec 0$ is the column $n$-tuple of zeros.

Comment: Could you explain to me how the equality holds?

Comment: How would you compute the determinant of that first matrix?

Comment: So $(detA)^{-1}$ = $\det\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \left(\vec 0\right)^T\\
\vec 0 & A^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\right)$?

Comment: Yes. Do you understand why?

Comment: I thought $det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{det(A)}$

Comment: Right. How do you find the determinant of a block-diagonal matrix?

Comment: if lower left block matrix is 0 then its the product of determinants of upperleft and lowerright block matrices right?

Comment: Yeah. That's the idea here.

Comment: ok now I see it. that makes $\det\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \left(\vec 0\right)^T\\
\vec 0 & A^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\right)$ equal to $(det(A)^{-1})$

Comment: Admittedly, that didn't quite work out as planned.  It's not immediately obvious to me why the math should work out from where I've got it.  It does seem to be along the right lines though, for what that's worth

Comment: I don't know if you can use the second to last formula [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), but that would finish the proof